# What are the text delimiters for use in the R function paste()?

Tags: r, bash

I am using some simple bash commands inside of an R for-loop to create some files with unique names.

Since the command arguments change with each iteration, I thought of using eval(parse(text=paste(system2(...)))), something like this:

```
index <- 1:5
for (i in index){
  eval(parse(text=paste('system2("echo","`some text`>> myfile_',i,'.txt")',sep = "")))
}
```

However, to define the text string that is the argument to echo, I need a third delimiter because single, double and back quotes don't work. The above code with back quotes produces five lines of:

```
 sh: some: command not found
```

while using the other quotes produces other errors.

Are there other delimiters that will work in this case?

Comment: Why not construct it as `system2(paste(...))`?  The `eval(parse(text=...))` is for the birds (i.e. it's garbage).

Comment: In `paste()` you don't have to use `sep`.  You can do `paste("echo", "something", ">>", "x", i, ".txt", ...)`